# Difficulty understanding layout_alignWithParentIfMissing

Tags: android, android-layout

I don't understand the meaning of `layout_alignWithParentIfMissing` for the `TextView` attribute.

I read the following [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing):

`android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing`

If set to true, the parent will be used as the anchor when the anchor cannot be be found for `layout_toLeftOf`, `layout_toRightOf`, etc.

Must be a boolean value, either `true` or `false`.

Please explain to me.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This apply only when using RelativeLayout.

If You set element to be toLeftOf some other element it means it will be on the left of this element.

But if this element will be missing, because You delete it for example it will be align to parent.

Take this example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="102dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

See what happens If You delete textView1 but don't touch textView2.

It will go to the bottom, on left(not right because it is inside of parent)

Android will position element relative to parent instead of element it should be because it is missing.

If it is false parameters relating to missing elements will be ignored.

Comment: Invalid layout param in a TextView: 
 layout_alignWithParentIfMissing - this error is coming

Answer (score 2):

Another sample. I have just used.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <Button
       android:id="@+id/streamOverflow"
       android:layout_width="50dp"
       android:layout_height="30dp"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:background="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
       android:focusable="false" />

    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/delete_time"
       style="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Disappears "
       android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/streamOverflow"
       android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
     />
</RelativeLayout>
```

if "streamOverflow" is missing, "delete_time" textview behaves like having android:layout_alignParentRight="true" property.

Answer (score 0):

In Relative Layouts, the position of a View can be specified relative to another View.

The tags **layout_toLeftOf** and **layout_toRightOf** position the view relative to an 'anchor' view object. When this anchor View is missing, the tag **alignWithParentIfMissing**, will align your view with the parent view.